# .net core get certificate private key to work with GRPC

Tags: c#, .net-core, certificate, grpc, x509certificate2

I create a self sign certificate. Later I create a google GRPC server who needs a certificate and key file. I try to get the infos from a loaded .net certificate. I get the cert but I have problems with the key file. I dont get the correct key format from the stored cert.

That is only a shot example. Normally I want to store the cert in at the .net cert store and when the grpc service ic created I want to read the cert and key from the store. With that I will instantiate the service.

Cert creation:

```
 openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -out myCert.crt -keyout myCert.key -config cert.conf
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in myCert.crt -inkey myCert.key -out myCert.pfx -passin pass: -passout pass:
```

Then I load the cert as a .net certificate (normally I will get it from the store):

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("myCert.pfx", "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
// some stringbuild before to add -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
var privateKeyFromDotNetCert = Convert.ToBase64String(x509Certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportRSAPrivateKey());
// for reference read the original key..only to shwo the problem
var serverkey = File.ReadAllText("myCert.key");
```

privateKeyFromDotNetCert is different to the original server key.

later I try to

```
  var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(cacert, serverkey);
  var sslCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair> { keypair }, cacert, false);
```

with serverKey it works fine but not with the extracted key from the .net certificate. Is it possible to get the correct key from the .net certificate?

[Cert creation from .net cert](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8978)

With the first answer I tried:

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.Append("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----");
  builder.AppendLine(Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportPkcs8PrivateKey(),Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));
  builder.Append("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

  privateKeyFromDotNetCert = builder.ToString();
```

This was working. privateKeyFromDotNetCert  is not equal to serverkey. But accepted from the grpc service.

Comment: The padding mode for key may be different from application using JSON and a c#.  Padding add random bytes to end of key to make key look like a fixed size (256,512, 1024)  to make it harder for hackers to determine size of key.  JSON and c# modes are different.  So you may have issues with keys matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment says you're prepending `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` (and presumably appending `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`), but the export method you chose (ExportRSAPrivateKey) doesn't match that format.  Try `ExportPkcs8PrivateKey`, which exports in the PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo format, which matches the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` header.  (ExportRSAPrivateKey produces a PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey, which is `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.)

You probably also want to use the `Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks` option.