# How to use windows store certificate (X509Certificate2) in GRPC server using .Net framework 4.7?

Tags: c#, grpc, x509certificate2, grpc-c#

I am getting certificate from Windows 10 certificate store. I got the X509Certificate2 from the windows certificate store. Now, how can I use this `X509Certificate2` in SslServerCredentials.
I know I can use SSL as follows:

```
var serverKey = File.ReadAllText("C:/repos/TestCert/server-key.pem");
var keyPair = new KeyCertificatePair(serverCert, serverKey);
var caCert = File.ReadAllText("C:/repos/TestCert/client-cert.pem");
var servCred = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>() { keyPair }, caCert, true);
```

But I am not having all the above certificates in separate location. I just want to use the certificates that are already available on the windows certificate store. I got the `X509Certificate2` class object from windows store. How can I use this `X509Certificate2` with `SslServerCredentials` class.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777001/net-core-get-certificate-private-key-to-work-with-grpc. Looks like you have to extract the cert and key 'manually' from the X509Certificate2...

Comment: Thanks! I have seen this link but not able to extract all the data which is required to create the object of the class SslServerCredentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, your certificate *must* have its private key marked as exportable when added to the store, without this there will be an error. I hacked this together a couple of years ago probably targeting .NET Framework 4.7 (but possibly 4.8) - the certificate export code is entirely derived from other Stack Overflow answers (including possibly the one linked in the comments)

```
public static class CertificateExporter
{
    public static string ExportX509CertificateAsPEM(this X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
        
        AppendByteArrayAsPEM(builder, certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));
        builder.AppendLine("-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

        return builder.ToString();
    }
    
    private static void AppendByteArrayAsPEM(StringBuilder builder, byte[] input)
    {
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(input);

        for (int i = 0; i < base64.Length; i += 64)
        {
            var line = base64.Substring(i, Math.Min(64, base64.Length - i));
            builder.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }

    public static string ExportX509PrivateRSAKey(this X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        var csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

        if (csp.PublicOnly)
            throw new ArgumentException("CSP does not contain a private key", "csp");

        var parameters = csp.ExportParameters(true);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            writer.Write((byte)0x30); // SEQUENCE
            using (var innerStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var innerWriter = new BinaryWriter(innerStream);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, new byte[] { 0x00 }); // Version
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Modulus);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Exponent);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.D);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.P);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Q);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DP);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DQ);
                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.InverseQ);
                var length = (int)innerStream.Length;
                EncodeLength(writer, length);
                writer.Write(innerStream.GetBuffer(), 0, length);
            }

            var outputStream = new StringWriter();

            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length).ToCharArray();
            outputStream.WriteLine("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
            // Output as Base64 with lines chopped at 64 characters
            for (var i = 0; i < base64.Length; i += 64)
            {
                outputStream.WriteLine(base64, i, Math.Min(64, base64.Length - i));
            }

            outputStream.WriteLine("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");

            return outputStream.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static void EncodeLength(BinaryWriter stream, int length)
    {
        if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", "Length must be non-negative");
        if (length < 0x80)
        {
            // Short form
            stream.Write((byte)length);
        }
        else
        {
            // Long form
            var temp = length;
            var bytesRequired = 0;
            while (temp > 0)
            {
                temp >>= 8;
                bytesRequired++;
            }

            stream.Write((byte)(bytesRequired | 0x80));
            for (var i = bytesRequired - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                stream.Write((byte)(length >> (8 * i) & 0xff));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void EncodeIntegerBigEndian(BinaryWriter stream, byte[] value, bool forceUnsigned = true)
    {
        stream.Write((byte)0x02); // INTEGER
        var prefixZeros = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            if (value[i] != 0) break;
            prefixZeros++;
        }

        if (value.Length - prefixZeros == 0)
        {
            EncodeLength(stream, 1);
            stream.Write((byte)0);
        }
        else
        {
            if (forceUnsigned && value[prefixZeros] > 0x7f)
            {
                // Add a prefix zero to force unsigned if the MSB is 1
                EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros + 1);
                stream.Write((byte)0);
            }
            else
            {
                EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros);
            }

            for (var i = prefixZeros; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                stream.Write(value[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then to create the credentials:

```
public class SslCredentialReader
{

    public SslServerCredentials CreateSslServerCredentials(string subject)
    {
        var certificate = GetServerCertificate(subject);
        var keyPair = new KeyCertificatePair(certificate.ExportX509CertificateAsPEM(),
            certificate.ExportX509PrivateRSAKey());
        return new SslServerCredentials(new[] {keyPair});
    }
    
    public X509Certificate2 GetServerCertificate(string subject)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject, true);
        store.Close();
        
        if (certificates.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"No certificate matching the subject name {subject} could be found");
        
        return certificates[0];
    }
}
```

I had this code working, but it's on an old branch and untested, hopefully it should be enough to get you there.

Comment: I'll check and let you know..

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed answer. The certificate stored in windows store is not having private key. It is giving error as you already mentioned.

Comment: Can you please share the client side code also? I am able to start the server using your code. But client is not able to connect to it.

Comment: I have a feeling I was using a .NET Core client - and the gRPC library is a bit different between the two. One critical point is that the client must trust the certificate that you are using